# C# .NET MVC cannot publish the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I cannot publish as File System.
Temp file shown that

> 10/26/2018 5:13:04 PM System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window
>   for more details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__127.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> ===================

Comment: Look at ProfileSelectorViewModel make sure that class is valid.

Comment: `Check the Output window for more details.` What did the Output window say?

Comment: Copying file obj\Debug\build.force to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\build.force failed. Could not find file 'obj\Debug\build.force'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try publishing via cmd. open cmd on the project root path and run this command

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64
```

this will create publish folder at **bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64\publish**

Comment: **I get an error message**

MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.403\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when migrate my project 2.1 to 2.2. It worked on local well. Then I have solved it with;

- Remove publish profile
- Create new publish profile

That is it. VS kept old profile with old dotnet core version.